# Calculating a different partition function of E&M leads to wrong results?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unitarity

Consider pure a $U(1)$ Yang-Mills action
$$S=-\frac{1}{4g^2}\int d^4xF^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$$
Usually, one calculates the corresponding partition function $\mathcal{Z}(J^{\mu})$ by adding some external field $J^{\mu}$ which couples to $A^{\mu}$ minimally. Let's say I decide to instead calculate the partition function $\mathcal{Z}(J^{\mu\nu})$ which has an external field $J^{\mu\nu}$ which couple to $F^{\mu\nu}$ minimally. Explicitly
$$\mathcal{Z}(J^{\mu\nu})=\int d\mu(A)\exp{\Big(iS+i\frac{1}{2}\int F_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu}}\Big)$$

I then can use this partition function to calculate correlation functions of $F_{\mu\nu}$.

However when you try this, you end up getting nonsensical results. Since this action is quadratic, the calculation is done by solving the equations of motion and plugging it back in to the action. The $A^\mu$ equations of motion are

$$\frac{1}{g^2}\partial_{\nu}F^{\nu\mu}=\partial_{\nu}J^{\nu\mu}$$

Which has a simple solution 
$$F^{\mu\nu}=g^2J^{\mu\nu}+C^{\mu\nu}$$
Where $C^{\mu\nu}$ is some divergence-less antisymmetric tensor. Plugging this general solution back in to the action, $J^{\mu\nu}$ and $C^{\mu\nu}$ decouple, and we have a partition function (after normalization)
$$\mathcal{Z}(J^{\mu\nu})=\exp{\Big(\frac{ig^2}{4}\int d^4xJ^{\mu\nu}J_{\mu\nu}\Big)}$$

Which appears to say that the two point correlation function for $F_{\mu\nu}$ is 
$$\langle F_{\mu\nu}(x)F_{\rho\sigma}(y)\rangle=-ig^2(\eta_{\mu\rho}\eta_{\nu\sigma}-\eta_{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\nu\rho})\delta^4(x-y)$$

This is certainly not true, or else the theory would not be unitary. It also just doesn't make any sense!

What is inherently wrong with choosing a partition function like this to calculate the correlation functions I want?

**Edit**

I should emphasize that the whole point of considering this new partition function $\mathcal{Z}(J^{\mu\nu})$ is to make calculating $F_{\mu\nu}$ correlation functions more efficient. With the usual prescription for the partition function $\mathcal{Z}(J^{\mu})$, one can calculate $A^{\mu}$ correlation functions by picking a particular gauge and then using those to construct the field strengths. Doing it that way is just more work. But it appears that for some reason $\mathcal{Z}(J^{\mu\nu})$ is not physically sensible, which I am now trying to understand by posting on this site.

Comment: This is extremely hard to follow. Have you forgotten that the path integral is over $A_\mu$, not $F_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: I apologize, can you suggest ways to make it more clear? I did not forget that it was a path integral over $A^{\mu}$, I used this fact when I solve the equations of motion for $A^{\mu}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to introduce sources $J^{\mu\nu}$ for $F_{\mu\nu}$. However, your calculation of the path integral doesn't work because the measure is not $dF_{\mu\nu}$ but instead $dA_\mu$ (to phrase things somewhat roughly).

Your end result is what you would get if $F_{\mu\nu}$ were an independent variable and you tried to calculate $\int DF \exp(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + J^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu})$ which is indeed Gaussian. (I say "tried" because this integral explodes: you need a differential operator between the $F$s to make any sense of this beyond simply defining it to equal your $\mathcal Z(J^{\mu\nu})$.)

You can perhaps view the Fadeev-Popov procedure for this $U(1)$ gauge theory as a "change of variables" $A\to F$ that properly incorporates the Jacobian of this transformation into account.

Comment: I believe I did use the measure $dA_{\mu}$. This why I solved the $A_{\mu}$ equations of motion rather than the $F_{\mu\nu}$ equations of motion.

Comment: You solved the $A_\mu$ EOMs for $F_{\mu\nu}$ rather than $A_\mu$.

Comment: I agree however that if I were to use the measure $dF_{\mu\nu}$, I would get the same answer. This is because the e.o.m. of $F_{\mu\nu}$ is simply $F_{\mu\nu}=g^2J_{\mu\nu}$. Since $J$ and $C$ decouple in the action there is no difference in the final answer.

Comment: But the $A_{\mu}$ never appears by itself in the action, so I don't actually have to find $A_{\mu}$.

Comment: The point is not determining the action in terms of $A$; rather, it's to do the path integral, which under certain conditions (most relevantly here for Gaussian integrals) means that you "solve the EOMs". However, the path integral for a theory with gauge symmetry is *not* Gaussian owing precisely to the presence of gauge symmetry, so its calculation is more complicated than just ``solving the EOMs''. (You need the FP procedure.)

If the EOMs *did* fix $A$ in terms of $F$, you would not have gauge symmetry, and your procedure would be correct.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the need for introducing ghosts. They are needed so that one can do perturbation theory in a gauge invariant way. If you can calculate the partition function without resorting to perturbation theory, you actually don't need them. In particular, at no point in my solution did I need to pick a gauge. Integrating over all gauge fields, including gauge equivalent ones, is not a problem at the non-perturbative level, since this will only contribute a large volume factor for gauge invariant expectation values that you would simply divide out for normalization purposes.